# Celery: making worker to execute x number of task per second

Tags: redis, celery

I am using Celery to execute sending mail task.

Sending one email corresponds to one task.

The SMTP server I am using takes only 24 send mail request per second. If it exceeds it limit error is thrown.

How can I control my worker to send only 24 (or x) task per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery lets you control that via the [rate limits](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#rate-limits)